# How to check if a word is in a list and if it exists in an item of the list then get the index number of the item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list called A

```
A = ["How are you","I am good","What are you doing?"]
```

I want to search for a word "good" and if it is found in the list then i want to get the item's index number in which the word has been found.

Desired output:

```
A = ["How are you","I am good","What are you doing?"]

B = "good"
```

Result =>

"good" word was found in list A[1]

i want to get the index number of the list's item in which the word was found.

Comment: What if B = "you"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I made a function):

```
A = ["How are you","I am good","What are you doing?"]
B = "how"

def FindWordInList(list,item):
    index = 0
    for string in list:
        index += 1
        for word in string.split():
            if word.lower() == item:
                #Subtracts one from the list as list index starts at 0
                return index - 1

    print("Could not find the word {} in the list".format(item))

indexofword = FindWordInList(A,B)
print("{} word was found in list A[{}]".format(B,indexofword))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Use Ajax1234's method as it probably faster, and uses less lines of code than mine

Comment: Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of manually counting up the index.

Comment: How can I print out the item of the list in which the word was found?

Comment: Add the following line to the bottom: print("The sentence {} was found was {}".format(B, A[indexofword]))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
A = ["How are you","I am good","What are you doing?"]
B = "good"
d = [(i, a) for i, a in enumerate(A) if B in a]
print("Elements found", d[0][-1]) #printing what elements contain "good"
print("'{}' was found in list A[{}]".format(B, d[0][0]) if d else "'{}' not found".format(B))
```

Output:

```
'Elements found', 'I am good'
'good' was found in list A[1]
```

Comment: How can I print out the item of the list in which the word was found?

Comment: You might consider `if B in a.split()` if you don't want to catch accidental hits like "goodies" or so...